# How to send an image to the server in react-konva

Tags: react-konva

I created a canvas in `react-konva`, and created a text and sticker. How do I send this to the server?

I was able to try something like this:

1. `stageRef.current.toJSON();`
2. `stageRef.current.toDataURL()`

URL length of `console.log()` in method 2 is too long.
I'm afraid that if I use `aws s3` later, the fee will be high

I'm trying to do it with method 1, but when I took a picture of the console and checked it, the class name table was output in json format.

I want to implement it the way I want to save this json to server and load it from server when displaying.

```js
import {
  Stage,
  Layer,
} from 'react-konva';

<Stage>
     <Layer>
           .... 
      </Layer>
</Stage>
```

I think I should be responsible for writing the above tag as a skeleton and putting a value on it, but I can't figure out how to do it here. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your original question "How to send an image", then you aprroach with `stageRef.current.toDataURL()` is correct. It returns base64 string of image. And it may be large, depending on stage size. Usually it is used when you want to "export" a canvas and save a final "non-editable later" version.

If you want to save a "design" and its structure, then you should save state of your React application. Probably as JSON. Then load from it and set into state again.